# Android native app - How to get the Text inside the class android.view.view

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I am a novice & trying to Automate an Application. I am opening a page which loads dynamic texts (For Eg : A Book) , which has a the following XML source,

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<hierarchy index="0" class="hierarchy" rotation="0" width="1080" height="1794">  
  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="name" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" displayed="true">
    <android.view.ViewGroup index="0" package="name" class="android.view.ViewGroup" text="" resource-id="android:id/decor_content_parent" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" displayed="true">
      <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="name" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" displayed="true">
        <android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" package="name" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" displayed="true">
          <android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" package="name" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" text="" resource-id="name:id/main_reader_layout" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" displayed="true">
            <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="name" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="name:id/animation_body" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" displayed="true">
              <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="name" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="name:id/video_view_container" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" displayed="true" />
              <android.view.View index="1" package="name" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="name:id/highlight_link_view" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" displayed="true" />
              ***<android.view.View index="2" package="name" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="name:id/curl_ogl_view" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" displayed="true" />***
            </android.widget.FrameLayout>
            <android.widget.FrameLayout index="1" package="name" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="name:id/bookmark_region" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[972,0][1080,289]" displayed="true" />
            <android.widget.TextView index="2" package="name" class="android.widget.TextView" text="138 of 218" resource-id="name:id/reader_page_info" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1798][1080,1920]" displayed="true" />
          </android.widget.RelativeLayout>
        </android.widget.RelativeLayout>
      </android.widget.FrameLayout>
    </android.view.ViewGroup>
  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>
```

Where

```
class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="name:id/curl_ogl_view"
```

contains the text.

I am trying to get the text and then passing it to Array or string. Please let me know if i can get the text in the page.

Please find the sample code,

```java
WebElement viewContainer = (WebElement) driver.findElement(By.id("name:id/curl_ogl_view"));
String getTextfromView = ((WebElement)viewContainer).getText().toString();
System.out.println("length::::"+getTextfromView.length());
System.out.println("length::::"+getTextfromView);
```

Please find the output when i run the above code,

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0 Feb 27, 2020 1:18:10 PM
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0 INFO:
>   Detected dialect: W3C Pass length::::0 length:::: PASSED: texttest
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Kindly let me know if any other info is required.

Comment: <android.view.View index="2" package="name" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="name:id/curl_ogl_view" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" displayed="true" />
            </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                      </android.widget.RelativeLayout>
        </android.widget.RelativeLayout>

Comment: I could not Attach the XML source, I could only attach the partial source, Please find it above

Answer (score 0):

class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="name:id/curl_ogl_view"

As per your xmL dom the class that you've mentioned in the above line does not seem to contain any text.
try finding the correct element which contains the text.
maybe you can share the link or something for the complete dom it'll be more helpful.

Comment: That is the whole page source. the text loads dynamically.  

I tried with all the following resource-id, but no Luck.  

`android:id/decor_content_parent
android:id/content
name:id/main_reader_layout
name:id/animation_body
name:id/curl_ogl_view
name:id/video_view_container
name:id/highlight_link_view`.  
  
I get the same response   
length::::0. 
length::::